# Check if Selected Range is Empty vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to achieve :

1. if the Range A date is < Current Date the MsgBox show it cannot be edit.
2. if the Range A date is = Current Date then it can be edit.
3. if the Range A date is empty then it can be edit.

I can only do No.1 and No.2 but No.3 is not able to do it.
Below here is my code. Kindly advise. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'TEST
If Range("A" & Selection.Row).Value < Date Then
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123456"
    MsgBox "Only today's date row can be edited!", vbInformation, "TEST"
ElseIf Range("A" & Selection.Row).Value = Date Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123456"
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("A" & Selection.Row).Value) = Fals Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123456"
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Or ```ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & Selection.Row).Value) Then```

Comment: `= Fals` should be `= False`

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` to prevent typos. • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: You dont need  = False on last condition, if you want to enable edit if empty

Comment: @Zan May I ask you to let us know if your issue is solved ?

Comment: @Dorian hi still not working